# Finding how many number sequences are in the string and handling each

Tags: java, regex, string

I am working on an address string that includes zipcode and house number.

In the string, the first number sequence is the house number and the second (and longer one) is the zipcode.

sometimes, one of these is missing. a broken address with no house number or without a zipcode. I still need to handle these situations.

I know I can use `matches(".*\\d+.*")` for finding if there are numbers in the string... but it's not enough.

I need to:

1. find out how many number sequences are in the string
2. how to handle each of the sequence separately.

note- address may be longer than usual, having more chars or info from the other and such. So using `substring` based on `length()-X` will not work properly and may even bug the code.

Any ideas how do I handle this situation?

edit - addresses are in hebrew... so here is a translation of a few -

CityName, 3659000

CityName [zipcode:  9010000 ]

StreetName 151 ,CityName, 2020000

POB 117 ,CityName [zipcode:  1790200 ]

StreetName  ,CityName [zipcode:  3005600 ]

Comment: Please post examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few example strings or more information about the strings should be desirable. You can read character per character of the string and check if it is a number or process it like you want.

The way I would do it is to traverse the string and rember the begin positions (max 2 in your case) where numbers begin and for how many positions. Then with substring you can easily extract them, convert them to a number and check which one is the smallest. That will be the house number.

Comment: i guess that could work. will try and tell if its okay. still , i would expect java to have a solution for it so im still open for more solutions!

Comment: I would expect that too, but don't know java enough. Maybe you should search for (built in) pattern matching algorithms.

Comment: actually it works good enough. maybe in the future when ill want to expand my knowledge.
thanks!